# Manual refresh breaks angularJS routing

Tags: angularjs

I am currently building my first angularJS project (Yay for me). Everything worked fine in a development environment (XAMPP 5.6 on OSX El Capitan).

Since I was curious how this would work in a production envoriment, I booted up a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu. I did a default apache2 install.

Now when I visit the droplet link, everything works fine. The problem is that when I manually refresh the site, the routing breaks, and I get the following message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /{INSERT RANDOM PAGE HERE} was not found on this server.
```

This is a small piece of my routing:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/assets/pages/home.php',
                controller: 'MainController'
            }).when('/registreren', {
                templateUrl: '/assets/pages/registreer.php',
                controller: 'MainController'
            }).when('/profielen/:user', {
                templateUrl: "/assets/pages/profielen.php",
                controller: 'profielController',
                controllerAs: "profiel"
            })
```

And the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Now I'm wondering is this is something that can be fixed quickly, quietly and especially easy

Is this a bugg in the routing system, or something that needs to be fixed within apache?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is most likely with the rewrite rules. Are rewrite rules allowed in .htaccess with your apache configuration?

Comment: @datasage yes, mod rewrite is enabled. Sorry for the late answer

Comment: There is a setting called AllowOverride that can control which directives are allowed in the .htaccess file. However, if you have access to it, its generally preferable to put the .htaccess settings into the rest of your site config.

Comment: You can also enable `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` to see how its handling the rewrites and if you need make any changes.

Comment: @datasage i checked the `AllowOverride` and I set it to All, this does not seem to make any difference. Nor does moving the rewrite rules to `apache2.conf`